# Tracking Chnages in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I encounter a real difficulty in tracking changes and updates in the company models.

I research the tool abilities a lot, but still didn't find the golden way that match my requirements of:

1. Provide indication `where` was a change
2. `What` was the change
3. Keep the `original` model state, aside to the `up-to-date` state

EA offers the following ways:

- Baselines
- Version Control
- Clone
- Change Elements

None of them provides indication on what exactly was the change and where.
**What is the easiest way to manage the changes effectively?**

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the last resort: audit. Turn on auditing and you can get a lot more information. Of course this also has its drawbacks

- it uses a lot of space
- there are still changes that are not tracked in the detail you might need it.

Turn it on at `Project/Auditing`. More information [here](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/the_model_repository/the_audit_view.html).

Additionally you could think of writing triggers, but I would not recommend that since it makes your repository almost unmaintainable.

Auditing is of course also no silver bullet. Tracking changes is tedious. And personally I would not spend too much effort in this "accusation mode". Better spend your energy in driving the model towards the company goals. **Nobody needs yesterday's model.**

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Can you please provide a link to auditing best practices in EA 13?

Comment: I have added a link to Sparx' site.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some scripts to handle change management in EA.

The idea is that the user links the changed items to a change request element that represents a workitem, project, change request, bug,...

Each link contains the date, user and a comment for the change to that item.

The scripts are part of the open source [EA VBScript library](https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-VBScript-Library):

The [main script](https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-VBScript-Library/blob/master/Projects/Project%20A/A%20Scripts/LinkToCRMain.vbs) is the following

```
'[path=\Projects\Project A\A Scripts]
'[group=Atrias Scripts]
!INC Local Scripts.EAConstants-VBScript
!INC Atrias Scripts.Util

' Script Name: LinkToCRMain
' Author: Geert Bellekens
' Purpose: Link Elemnents to a change
' Date: 2015-10-30
'
'


function linkItemToCR(selectedItem, selectedItems)
    dim groupProcessing
    groupProcessing = false
    'if the collection is given then we initialize the first item.
    if selectedItem is nothing then
        if not selectedItems is nothing then
            if selectedItems.Count > 0 then
                set selectedItem = selectedItems(0)
                if selectedItems.Count > 1 then
                    groupProcessing = true
                end if
            end if
        end if
    end if
    if selectedItem is nothing then
        set selectedItem = Repository.GetContextObject()
    end if

    'get the select context item type
    dim selectedItemType
    selectedItemType = selectedItem.ObjectType
    select case selectedItemType
    case otElement, otPackage, otAttribute, otMethod, otConnector :
        'if the selectedItem is a package then we use the Element part of the package
        if selectedItemType = otPackage then
            set selectedItem = selectedItem.Element
        end if
        'get the logged in user
        Dim userLogin
        userLogin = getUserLogin
        dim lastCR as EA.Element
        set lastCR = nothing
        dim CRtoUse as EA.Element
        set CRtoUse = nothing
        set lastCR = getLastUsedCR(userLogin)
        'get most recent used CR by this user

        if not selectedItem is nothing then
            dim lastComments
            lastComments = vbNullString
            'if there is a last CR then we ask the user if we need to use that one
            if not lastCR is nothing then
                dim response
                if groupProcessing then
                    response = Msgbox("Link all " & selectedItems.Count & " elements to change: """ & lastCR.Name & """?", vbYesNoCancel+vbQuestion, "Link to CR")
                elseif not isCRLinked(selectedItem,lastCR) then
                    response = Msgbox("Link element """ & selectedItem.Name & """ to change: """ & lastCR.Name & """?", vbYesNoCancel+vbQuestion, "Link to CR")
                end if
                'check the response
                select case response
                    case vbYes
                        set CRToUse = lastCR
                    case vbCancel
                        'user cancelled, stop altogether
                        Exit function
                end select
            end if
            'If there was no last CR, or the user didn't want to link that one we let the user choose one
            if CRToUse is nothing then
                dim CR_id       
                CR_ID = Repository.InvokeConstructPicker("IncludedTypes=Change") 
                if CR_ID > 0 then
                    set CRToUse = Repository.GetElementByID(CR_ID)
                end if
            else
                'user selected same change as last time. So he might want to reuse his comments as well
                lastComments = getLastUsedComment(userLogin)
            end if
            'if the CRtoUse is now selected then we link it to the selected element
            if not CRToUse is nothing then
                dim linkCounter
                linkCounter = 0
                'first check if this CR is not already linked
                if isCRLinked(selectedItem,CRToUse) and not groupProcessing then
                    MsgBox "The CR was already linked to this item", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation ,"Already Linked" 
                else
                    'get the comments to use
                    dim comments
                    comments = InputBox("Please enter comments for this change", "Change Comments",lastComments)
                    if len(comments) > 2 then
                        if groupProcessing then
                            for each selectedItem in selectedItems
                                'check the object type
                                selectedItemType = selectedItem.ObjectType
                                select case selectedItemType
                                case otElement, otPackage, otAttribute, otMethod, otConnector :
                                    if not isCRLinked(selectedItem,CRToUse) then
                                        linkToCR selectedItem, selectedItemType, CRToUse, userLogin, comments
                                        linkCounter = linkCounter + 1
                                    end if
                                end select
                            next
                            if linkCounter > 0 then
                                MsgBox "Successfully linked " & selectedItems.Count & " elements to change """ & CRToUse.Name& """"  , vbOKOnly + vbInformation ,"Elements linked" 
                            else
                                MsgBox "No links created to change " & CRToUse.Name & "." & vbNewLine & "They are probably already linked" , vbOKOnly + vbExclamation ,"Already Linked" 
                            end if
                        else
                            linkToCR selectedItem, selectedItemType, CRToUse, userLogin, comments
                        end if
                    else
                        MsgBox "The CR has not been linked because no comment was provided", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation ,"No CR link" 
                    end if
                end if
            end if
        end if
    case else
        MsgBox "Cannot link this type of element to a CR" & vbNewline & "Supported element types are: Element, Package, Attribute, Operation and Relation"
    end select
end function



function isCRLinked(item, CR)
    dim taggedValue as EA.TaggedValue
    isCRLinked = false
    for each taggedValue in item.TaggedValues
        if taggedValue.Value = CR.ElementGUID then
            isCRLinked = true
            exit for
        end if
    next
end function

function linkToCR(selectedItem, selectedItemType, CRToUse, userLogin, comments)
    Session.Output "CRToUse: " & CRToUse.Name & " userLogin: " & userLogin & " comments: " & comments
    dim crTag 
    set crTag = nothing
    set crTag = selectedItem.TaggedValues.AddNew("CR","")
    if not crTag is nothing then
        crTag.Value = CRToUse.ElementGUID
        crTag.Notes = "user=" & userLogin & ";" & _
                     "date=" & Year(Date) & "-" & Right("0" & Month(Date),2) & "-" & Right("0" & Day(Date),2) & ";" & _
                     "comments=" & comments
        crTag.Update
    end if
end function

function getLastUsedCR(userLogin)
    dim wildcard
    dim sqlDateString
    if Repository.RepositoryType = "JET" then
        wildcard = "*"
        sqlDateString = " mid(tv.Notes, instr(tv.[Notes],'date=') + len('date='),10) "
    Else
        wildcard = "%"
        sqlDateString = " substring(tv.Notes, charindex('date=',tv.[Notes]) + len('date='),10) "
    end if
    dim sqlGetString
    sqlGetString = "select top 1 o.Object_id " & _
                    " from (t_objectproperties tv " & _
                    " inner join t_object o on o.ea_guid = tv.VALUE) " & _
                    " where tv.[Notes] like 'user=" & userLogin & ";" & wildcard & "' " & _
                    " order by  " & sqlDateString & " desc, tv.PropertyID desc "
    dim CRs
    dim CR as EA.Element
    set CR = nothing
    'get the last CR
    set CRs = getElementsFromQuery(sqlGetString)
    if CRs.Count > 0 then
        set CR = CRs(0)
    end if

    set getLastUsedCR = CR
end function

function getLastUsedComment(userLogin)
    dim wildcard
    dim sqlDateString
    dim sqlCommentsString
    if Repository.RepositoryType = "JET" then
        wildcard = "*"
        sqlDateString = " mid(tv.Notes, instr(tv.[Notes],'date=') + len('date='),10) "
        sqlCommentsString = " mid(tv.Notes, instr(tv.[Notes],'comments=') + len('comments=')) "
    Else
        wildcard = "%"
        sqlDateString = " substring(tv.Notes, charindex('date=',tv.[Notes]) + len('date='),10) "
        sqlCommentsString = " substring(tv.Notes, charindex('comments=',tv.[Notes]) + len('comments='), datalength(tv.Notes))  "
    end if
    dim sqlGetString
    sqlGetString = "select top 1 " & sqlCommentsString & " as comments " & _
                    " from (t_objectproperties tv " & _
                    " inner join t_object o on o.ea_guid = tv.VALUE) " & _
                    " where tv.[Notes] like 'user=" & userLogin & ";" & wildcard & "' " & _
                    " order by  " & sqlDateString & " desc, tv.PropertyID desc "
    dim queryResult 
    queryResult = Repository.SQLQuery(sqlGetString)
    Session.Output queryResult
    dim results
    results = convertQueryResultToArray(queryResult)
    if Ubound(results) > 0 then
        getLastUsedComment = results(0,0)
    else
        getLastUsedComment = vbNullString
    end if
end function
```